# Two terminal measurement of BJT?

Tags: bjt

[image]

When I measured two terminal IV curve of a BJT (positive terminal on emitter and negative on collector with base floating), the above graph is what I observed. How can I qualitatively explain this behavior?

Comment: If you had the probes both on the emitter, you should see a short circuit. Where did you actually have them?

Comment: @Hearth Oh my bad, I meant the negative terminal on collector. I edited the question.

Comment: so the positive terminal was at negative 8V with respect to the negative terminal, or was it the other way round?

Answer (score 2):

The base-emitter junction of an bipolar junction transistor behaves like a zener diode. That is, if it becomes reverse biased beyond its "breakdown" voltage, it suddenly begins to conduct, and will attempt to "clamp" the voltage across it.

In such a condition, with the collector being more negative than the emitter, the base-collector junction is forward biased, and the base-emitter "zener" junction is reverse biased. Therefore, the (negative) potential difference between emitter and collector required to enter this state of breakdown will be the sum of the forward voltage of the base-collector junction (0.7V) and the reverse breakdown voltage of the base-emitter junction (typically 8V).

In your case, that total seems to be exactly 8V, suggesting that the base-emitter junction of your particular device must have a reverse breakdown voltage of 7.3V. You are witnessing the combination of the two junction "diodes" clamping the potential difference across them to -8V. Note that you have effectively connected a very low impedance voltage source across those diodes, and as soon as the voltage source goes beyond -8V you see a sharp, uncontrolled rise of current as the diodes fight to keep it from increasing further.

To illustrate, here's the equivalent circuit, replacing an NPN device's junctions with diodes. The collector-base junction is represented by a regular silicon diode, but the base-emitter junction is a zener diode. I have also included a resistor, to avoid the violently large onset of current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9wiFF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, for voltages between collector and emitter greater than -8V, no current flows (bottom plot). With no current through R1, and no voltage across it, the collector potential (top plot) remains equal to the source.

As \$V_{CE}\$ becomes more and more negative, it eventually exceeds the combined forward voltage of Dcb and reverse breakdown voltage of Dbe, at which point the diodes conduct, and you see current beginning to flow. Importantly, you also see the clamping effect they have; the collector potential cannot descend further than 8V below the emitter.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing B-E "zenering" and "reverse beta"

7.4V is the base-emitter breakdown voltage after that the base-emitter junction starts conducting and current leaks from emitter to base and then flows base base to collector which turns the transistor on in the reverse direction. (allowing current to flow from emitter to collector)

At a little over 0.1A the over 800mW being dissipated has warmed the transistor enough to reduce the base-emitter breakdown voltage slightly.